# (First time using MATLAB) Examples for constructors of htensor

Tags: matlab, tensor, matlab-class

Unfortunately, I have no experience with Matlab and now I need a few visualizations in this program.
At the moment i'm working on tensors and their approximation possibilities.
More specifically with this preprint:

https://www.epfl.ch/labs/mathicse/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/04.2012_DK-CT.pdf

On the sixth page the author says: " To conveniently work with tensors in HTD, we have implemented a new Matlab class htensor, [...] available in the Tensor Toolbox".

Now I downloaded the Tensor Toolbox: https://www.tensortoolbox.org/
and unzip the folder.

On the seventh page he gives some examples of htensor constructions. For example " x = htensor ( [4 5 6 7 ] ) "

So can you help me with a tiny beginner code or implement a constructor?
If I type " x = htensor ( [ 4 5 6 7 ]) " I get this: ">> x = htensor ( [4 5 6 7 ] )
Unrecognized function or variable 'htensor'.

Did you mean:
x = tensor ( [4 5 6 7 ] ) ".
Im sorry that Im totally unexperienced in this topic. Hopefully you understand my lack of experience.

Comment: Have you added the toolbox folder(s) to Matlab's path? See [`addpath`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html)

Comment: you can check if the htensor function is on path by calling 'which htensor'. It should return the path to the function. If it is not on path it will return 'not found'  and as said in the previous comment, you need to add the toolbox to the path